# MONGODB return min value for a field if falls within last year otherwise return min value for collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that consists of documents in this format:

`{"_id":{"date_played":{"$date":"1998-03-28T00:00:00.000Z"},"course_played":4,"player_id":11},"score":[5,6,4,4,5,9,6,6,5,7,6,6,5,7,5,3,9,4],"handicap":30,"cash_won":0,"sort_order":6,"gross_score":102,"gross_sfpts":34,"skins_group":1,"score_differential":28,"pcc_adjustment":0,"player_name":"Dave"}`

By _id.player_id I am trying to return the min value of "score_differential" for records within the last year(_id.date_played), if no records in the last year then I want the min "score_differential" for the player in the collection.
I have tried lots of combinations but this is the closest I have got:-

Which returns the correct values but the problem is if a date is found within the year I get two records back, one with _id: false which has lowest in collection and one with _id: true which has lowest for year. My problem is that I only want one record back not two. Any help is much appreciated as I have spent days on this, relatively new to mongodb coming from mysql.

````
  {
    '$match': {
      '_id.player_id': 11
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        '$min': [
          {
            '$gt': [
              '$_id.date_played', {
                '$dateFromParts': {
                  'year': {
                    '$subtract': [
                      {
                        '$year': new Date()
                      }, 1
                    ]
                  }, 
                  'month': {
                    '$month': new Date()
                  }, 
                  'day': {
                    '$dayOfMonth': new Date()
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }, 
      'minWHI': {
        '$min': '$score_differential'
      }
    }
  }
] ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Thx but I no longer need a solution to this, I actually use the above code in a $lookup stage in another query and as that returns an array I end up with just one document returned where I can test the matched field for the values I need, I was just confused as I was trying to test each part of the main query separately and in doing so getting two documents.